# Commenting keyboard shortcut broken in Xcode 8.3.3

Tags: xcode8

I restarted, rebuilt, changed app name, cleared derived data, reboot again.  I literally just deleted and re-downloaded Xcode.  I have read and followed dozens of posts across the internet to no avail.

I am unable to try `sudo /usr/libexec/xpccachectl` as I am missing that command.  I tried 'installing additional components' in terminal but that asks for Xcode to have accessibility permission from system preferences.  I add it to the list.  Run the install components command and it just asks again.

Comment: Any reason not to use 9? Also, "Commenting broken" does not describe your problem in any meaningful way.

Comment: commenting multilines using command+/ does not work via the keyboard, and the option in editor/structure is greyed out.  i cannot use Xcode9 for work related reasons.